# How to execute the file that's running in python

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I've been trying to make a tkinter game that re-executes its self once it is finished. Here is the code I tried:

```py
from subprocess import run
.....
.....
.....
.....
run('python3 ' + __file__)
```

and

```py
from subprocess import run
from os.path import dirname
.....
.....
.....
.....
run('python3 ' + dirname(__file__) + filename)
```

But none of the solutions worked.
Is there a way that my program restarts at the end?
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, why restart the file, thus relying on OS-specific features, when you can create a loop that would restart the logic if needed

Comment: Better use exec somehow instead of fork+exec, not to end up with a tree of processes

Comment: The thing is the restart thing is in an if so i can't really do that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate its a tkinter program that has the hole thing restart once something happens.

Comment: link to the code : https://github.com/chboo1/games

Comment: for more precision.

Comment: _hello_ **hello**

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the program by placing it inside a loop:

```py
def start():
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....

while True:
    start()
```